# creating a directory in java

Tags: java, file, ioexception, creation, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to create a directory and copy files to it. The code I've implemented and its output is below. The problem seems self explanatory, but I'll make it explicit for those who can't tell.

### Problem

---

No matter what I do, I can't seem to create the destination file required to copy the file.

### Code

---

`get` is the file to be copied, and `dest` is the directory to which it will be copied. Line numbers and "`ERR>`" were added for clarity. I've commented out other methods of file creation which I've tried, but they all failed.

```
115:  private void copyTo(File get, File dest)
116:  {
117:    try
118:    {
119:      dest = new File((dest.getPath().endsWith(File.separator) ? dest.getPath() : dest.getPath() + File.separator) + get.getName());
120:      
121:      java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(get);
122:      if (dest.exists())
123:        while(!dest.delete());
124:      dest.mkdir();
125://      dest.createNewFile();
126://      java.io.FileWriter w = new java.io.FileWriter(dest);
127://      w.write("");
128:      System.out.println("Writing \"" + get + "\" to \"" + dest + "\"");
129:ERR>  java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(dest);
130:      int b;
131:      do
132:      {
133:        b = fis.read();
134:        fos.write(b);
135:      }while (b != -1);
136:    }
137:    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
138:    {
139://      System.err.println("404: \"" + get + "\"");
140:      ex.printStackTrace();
141:    }
142:    catch (java.io.IOException ex)
143:    {
144://      System.err.println("IO exception on \"" + get + "\"");
145:      ex.printStackTrace();
146:    }
147:  }
```

### Output

---

```
Writing "J:\warehouse.txt" to "J:\backup\warehouse.txt"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: J:\backup\warehouse.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
        at copy.TUI.copyTo(TUI.java:129)
        at copy.TUI.copy(TUI.java:110)
        at copy.TUI.run(TUI.java:102)
        at copy.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Comment: What is the return value from dest.mkdir()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dest.getParentFile().mkdir()`. This will create the parent dir for your dest file. In case multiple parent path elements might be missing you can use the `mkdirs()` method to create all missing directories recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix it myself. Pretty derpy of me to not see it in the first place...

```
  private void copyTo(File get, File dest)
  {
    try
    {
      File newDest = new File((dest.getPath().endsWith(File.separator) ? dest.getPath() : dest.getPath() + File.separator) + get.getName());

      java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(get);
      if (dest.exists())
       dest.delete();
      dest.mkdirs();
      dest.setWritable(true);
      dest.setReadable(true);
//      dest.createNewFile();
//      java.io.FileWriter w = new java.io.FileWriter(dest);
//      w.write("");
      System.out.println("Writing \"" + get + "\" to \"" + dest + "\"");
      java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(newDest);
      int b;
      do
      {
        b = fis.read();
        fos.write(b);
      }while (b != -1);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
//      System.err.println("404: \"" + get + "\"");
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex)
    {
//      System.err.println("IO exception on \"" + get + "\"");
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following -

```
dest = dest.isDirectory() ?  new File(dest, get.getName()):  new File(dest.getParentDirectory(), get.getName());
dest.getParentDirectory().mkdirs();
```